# Itty bitty radio buttons

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, mobile-web

It seems the radio buttons on mobile safari for VTC options after selecting “off topic” are tiny! Tested on IPS and SO and see the same behavior. See images below.

**EDIT**: I'm running iOS 11.1.1

> [image: tiny IPS]

---

> [image: tiny SE]

Comment: Have you tried using your pinky finger to vote instead?

Comment: @Snow Are you suggesting the OP currently votes with their middle finger?

Comment: I observe the same bug with iOS 11.4 on an iPhone 6, on all sites where I tried it. It seems that the radio buttons are the smaller the more text follows them.